# Changing title without changing prompt on Cygwin

Tags: bash, prompt, cygwin, window-title

I have the following shell script function from [this site](http://royontechnology.blogspot.ch/2008/06/setting-title-of-putty-terminal.html) that allows me to change the title in both Putty and Cygwin.  In Putty connected to a Linux host it changes the title and leaves the prompt as it was.  But in Cygwin it changes the title and then the prompt becomes a mere $ or # sign.

I would like to create a version for Cygwin that changes the title but leaves the prompt as it was.  (I know I should try to create one first on my own before posting here but prompt strings I have always found confusing.)

**EDIT:**  More specifically, in Cygwin I like the default prompt of `user@hostname` followed by the current directory.  I'd like to preserve THAT prompt.

**EDIT II:**  And I don't really care if the colors of the default Cygwin prompt are preserved, if that makes it easier.  I just want at the very least the directory in the prompt.

Here's what I have:

```
function wtitle {
  if [ "$TERM" == "xterm" ] ; then
    # Remove the old title string in the PS1, if one is already set.
    PS1=`echo $PS1 | sed -r 's/^\\\\\[.+\\\\\]//g'`
    export PS1="\[\033]0;$1 - \u@\h:\w\007\]$PS1"
  else
    echo "You are not working in xterm. I cannot set the title."
 fi
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Please add

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$'
```

as last line in your ~/.bashrc and login again or just run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what OP is asking for is to set the title of the window within which your terminal emulator is running. I'm confused by the references to PS1 since I'm able to achieve this by simply running this...

```
printf '\e]2;%s\a' "My Title"
```

At least this works with mintty 2.7 (+ Cygwin 2.8). (Perhaps things have changed in the years since the question was originally posted.)

Comment: I tried this on cygwin 2.7 and it doesn't work.

Comment: @w00t The terminal emulator is what matters which is why I mention mintty first and cygwin only parenthetically. What are you using?

Comment: I see.. mintty --version:
mintty 2.7.6 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)

Comment: @w00t  Should work. Is your current prompt modifying the title already? Try setting it to something basic like `PS1='$ '`. Make sure you don't have `PROMPT_COMMAND` set to something that would interfere.See if `echo -ne "\e]0;My Title\a"` works. Maybe `$TERM` value isn't compatible (?). I'm running out of ideas after these.

Comment: ah, yes, unsetting PS1 and trying again did the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the titles are not updating at all as soon as logged in to some SSH server, try installing the OpenSSH package from cygwin.

For me, cygwin was using some Windows 10 Pro internal version of OpenSSH that did not pass the title escape characters back through the SSH stack.

Posting this to maybe keep someone from spending an hour on this

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. You should always quote shell variables
   unless you have a good reason not to,
   and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
   So `echo $PS1` should be `echo "$PS1"`. 
   This causes the prompt to lose the space at the end;
   i.e., it becomes `$` rather than `$` . 
   And it may cause other problems in some cases.
2. Bash uses `\[`…`\]` to delimit escape sequences;
   i.e., characters that do not appear on screen as part of the prompt. 
   This includes the escape sequence to set the window title,
   but also the escape sequences to change color within the (visible) prompt. 
   Your script does

   ```
   s/ ^ \\\\\[ .+ \\\\\] //g
   ```

   (with spaces added for clarity). 
   At first glance,
   it looks like this is trying to remove ***all*** `\[`…`\]` sequences. 
   (Actually, there are *two* reasons why it doesn’t do that.) 
   The main problem with this is that `.+` matches
   the longest possible string of *any* characters. 
   This implies that it deletes everything
   from the beginning of the first `\[`…`\]` sequence
   to the end of the last `\[`…`\]` —
   in other words, everything up through the last color change.

   We want to delete only the escape sequence to set the window title. 
   We would normally change `.+` (where **`.`** matches *any* character)
   to a string of characters other than `]`. 
   But this is complicated by the fact that
   the escape sequence to set the window title ***contains*** a `]`,
   so we need to match up through the *second* `]`:

   ```
   s/^\\\\\[[^]]+][^]]+\\\\\]//g
   ```

   I’ll show this in context in a moment…
3. This is not a problem *per se,* but `` ` ``…`` ` `` is obsolete syntax. 
   You are advised to use `$(`…`)` instead. 
   Some posts seem to suggest that these are functionally interchangeable. 
   They are not; different quoting / escaping rules apply. 
   Luckily, this works to our advantage in this case. 
   When we switch over to `$(`…`)`,
   we can change the `sed` command to use fewer backslashes.
4. Another issue: using the `function` keyword is discouraged. 
   See below for the preferred syntax.

So, putting together all of the above, we get this:

```
wtitle() {
  if [ "$TERM" == "xterm" ] ; then
    # Remove the old title string in the PS1, if one is already set.
    PS1=$(echo "$PS1" | sed -r 's/^\\\[[^]]+][^]]+\\\]//g')
    export PS1="\[\033]0;$1 - \u@\h:\w\007\]$PS1"
  else
    echo "You are not working in xterm. I cannot set the title."
 fi
}
```

Arguably, even this is not perfect. 
It depends on the existing `PS1` value
having the window title escape sequence as the very first thing.